# Travis do not upload files using lftp

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, devops, travis-ci

This is my configuration:

```yaml
language: node_js
node_js:
  - '12'

cache: npm

script:
  - npm test
  - npm run build

after_success:
  - sudo apt-get -y install lftp
  - echo "set dns:order \"inet inet6\"" > ~/.lftprc
  - lftp -e "mirror -eR ./app ~/tmp" -u ${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD} ftp://${FTP_SERVER}
```

And everything works fine. Except the last command. When I'm trying to upload files to the server using this command it takes 1-2 minutes, but travis cannot do it at all. It says that time is out and raises an error. Even if I increase timeout to 30 minutes nothing really changes.

I want to test, build and then deploy my site to the server using FTP protocol. And as I've already said I can do it from my machine using `lftp`.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really tried to find the answer, but there's nothing. But istead I had found the solution - *Github Actions*. It works much better, then *Travis*.